# Display a pop up form once a button is clicked in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, popup, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to find a way to display a pop up form once a button is clicked. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

One option is to

- create a modal dialog page,
- put any contents you want there
- let the button navigate to a page within this application
- specify the previously created modal dialog page